# What is the correct way to postpone the usage of a f-string in 2022?

Tags: python, f-string

I already saw multiple threads about postponed usage of f-strings, but they are all relatively old.

So here are some examples I found:

```
# lambda-function as constant
POSTPONED_F_STRING = lambda x, y, z: f"Use variables: {x}, {y}, {z}"

# function/method
def fstr(template):
    return eval(f"f'{template}'")
```

Or is it even better to use the old str.format() in this case?
Any new stuff I didn't mention?

I would really like to here some input on the "right" way to do this, if there even is one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes just use `str.format`

Comment: Simply calling `str.format` at the appropriate time seems the most straightforward. However, opinion-based questions are not particularly encouraged on SO, so you may want to narrow down the criteria or context.

Answer (score 1):

`str.format` is your best option, yes, for the same syntax as an f-string.

`eval` is evil, as we should all know:

```
>>> fstr("' + __import__('os').system('uname') + '")
Darwin
```